# Codeigniter PHPExcel Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I have followed this tutorial here

https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/

and here

http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework/

However, I still get the PHPExcel_IOFactory not found error. I haven't found much help in this area. Is there an alternative excel plugin or is there a way to solve this?

This is my controllers construct

```
public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Excel');
    }
```

This is my controllers upload function

```
$objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); 
$objPHPExcel= PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($document_folder."/".$file_name.".".$file_extension);    
//        $this->response($objPHPExcel);
$objPHPExcel=$objReader->load($document_folder."/".$file_name.".".$file_extension); 
$totalrows=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
$objWorksheet=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  
for($i=2;$i<=$totalrows;$i++){ //2 is one row after the header rows
    $title= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();     
    $first_name= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();            
    $last_name= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue(); 
    $date_of_birth= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$i)->getValue(); 
    $email=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$i)->getValue();
    $phone_number=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5,$i)->getValue(); 
    $company=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6,$i)->getValue(); 
    $input=array(
          'title'=>$title, 
          'first_name'=>$first_name,
          'last_name'=>$last_name,
          'date_of_birth'=>$date_of_birth,
          'email'=>$email,
          'phone_number'=>$phone_number,
          'company'=>$company,
     );
```

Comment: What does your Excel.php library look like? Also, are you sure you have ALL of the PHPExcel files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember that PHPExcel is just PHP, and so is CodeIgniter. You don't have to load PHPExcel through another library. If fact, it doesn't do anything for you. I put all of the PHPExcel files in /third_party/, and then do this:

```
require_once( APPPATH . 'third_party/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
```

Notice that in the example I am using v1.8

If you want to use `$objReader` in multiple methods, then just make it a class property. So `$this->objReader` instead.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying. My third party folder has a PHPExcel file and a PHPExcel folder containing all the classes. My library folder contains a Excel.php file that just has this require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPExcel.php";
 
class Excel extends PHPExcel {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

Comment: I have also tried your method of adding the require_once into my controller but the same error happens

Comment: I realized what the mistake was. my PHPExcel_IOFactory file was modified because I read somewhere that I had to remove the PHPExcel_ part. Thank you for your help!